# How is it possible to have two variables with same names - one is global and another one is local?

Tags: c++, c

I understand that two variable can be declared of same name in two distinct function.
how can we declare a variable within a function which is already declared in the global scope?

Comment: That is why we have scope resolution operator `::`

Comment: What is the problem? Exactly like that. The local one is overriding the global.

Comment: @16tons Which is not applying to C..

Comment: Choose a language.

Comment: Try not to have global variables - then this problem goes away - along with a few others

Comment: @user7402493 check my answer and upvote if you find this helful

Comment: this question has a taste of everything I like about SO. 1) a new user submits a question and is never to be seen again. 2) The question get's downvoted instantly without anyone making any edits. 3) People actually answer the question, and proceed to be upvoted.

Answer (score 8):

This is called [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). In C++, you can use scope resolution operator `::` to refer to global variable from inside a block. The C language does not have this, however you may use the following technique to access global variable as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 100;

int main(void)
{      
    int a = 200;
    printf("%d\n", a); // prints 200

    // anonymous block used to refer to global a
    {
        extern int a;
        printf("%d\n", a); // prints 100
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even this is possible, be wary, that it may confuse other programmers, i.e. it violates "Don't be clever" principle.

Comment: Surprised to see how this can be done in C.  LSNED.

Comment: Yeah. That's interesting. But I guess there is no way to access the `a=200` thing if shadowed?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That's right. It is like one-way street.

Answer (score 5):

For C++ you can always use the resolution operator to specify what scope you are talking about (`::`)

However in C the rule is that the variable in the context of the more specific scope is used.

```
int num = 5;
int main()
{
     printf("%d\n", num);
     int num = 3;
     printf("%d\n", num);
     return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
5
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope of a variable is the part of he code where that variable is visible.
Therefore a global variable is visible everywhere but a local variable is visible only to a particular section of code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a=9;
int main()
{
    int a =8;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<::a;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above c++ code first output is 8 whereas second is 9.
Here both variables were visible in the code but using scope resolution operator you can decide which variable you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Said in simple terms, if multiple variables in a program have the same name, then there are fixed guidelines that the compiler follows as to which variable to pick for the execution. I'll go over them all in an example below.

Global variables, as the name suggests are declared outside of any function and are accessible in any part of the code. However, in the event of another variable with the same name as the global one, the local variable would get the higher "preference" for the part of the code that comes **after** it is declared.

For example,

```
    int num = 25;
    
    class Print
    {
        int num;
        Print();
    };

    Print::Print()
    {
        num = 98;
    }

    void PrintNumber(void)
    {
        int num = 12;
    }
    
    int main(void)
    {
        cout << num << endl;
    
        int num = 34;
        cout << num << endl;
    
        PrintNumber();
    
        Print object;
        cout << object.num << endl;
    }
```

I've tried to cover every possible scenario, please don't hesitate to inform me if I missed any scenario out. Anyways, the result of this program would be:

> 25
>
> 34
>
> 12
>
> 98

The first one is the global one; since the variable *num* of the class Print and the function PrintNumber() is localized to the object of the class and that function respectively, only the global variable is accessible here. Same for the second number, except a local variable with the same number *num* has a a higher privilege, so it is given a higher accessibility than the global variable (mind my erroneous English, sorry for that). Then when the PrintNumber() function is invoked, it prints the num of that local variable. Finally, an object of class Print will output the value stored in the num of that class.

Hope this answers your question.